# When I am querying from User object facing error Illegal assignment from List<User> to List<User>

Tags: apex, soql, query

When I am doing two SOQL queries in an apex method on User Object, facing an error like-

```
User u = [SELECT Id, IsActive FROM User WHERE username = 'some username'];

List<User> userList = [Select Id, Name From User];
```

[image]
[image]

Can someone please let me know is there anything I am missing in these SOQL queries?

Comment: You should probably include more context for this code because while the first query here _can_ be a problem, the second query should be fine. The dev console's error detector can spit out false positives and can take a while to update. What happens if you try to save this code despite those "problems"?

Comment: Hi, @DerekF I tried to fetch User for a single UserId and also tried to get all User as a list. But for both cases, the error is coming and the class is not getting saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a custom class called User somewhere else in your code. This is what's causing that confusing error message. I recommend that you refactor to change the class name from User to something else. Alternatively, use `Schema.User` to get the correct object:

```
Schema.User u = [SELECT Id, IsActive FROM User WHERE username = 'some username'];
List<Schema.User> userList = [Select Id, Name From User];
```

Comment: Exactly and Thank You very much for this solution.